# How to encrypt HTTP POST Data by HTML forms?

Tags: html, http, post, encryption, get

HTML forms send clear text data when it submit data using HTTP session, So my problem is how to send encrypted data using just form and what algorithm can be used?

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You can add enctype attribute to form such as enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: You should use https if you want data encrypted on submit, ecrypting client side is about as secure as plain text otherwise

Comment: Use HTTPS. This is a wheel you can only re-invent poorly and expensively.

Comment: After using Fiddler HTTPS decryption all packets converted to be plain-text. so what a solution for that problem.@dbugger